# Implementing a score system similar to Moon Patrol

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

I am working on an Android game scenario inspired by [Moon Patrol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBOKWCpwGfM).

My beta version is available for beta test from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.android.buggy

In my case, I got the elapsed time in seconds for reaching a checkpoint, and I could reward either a fixed bonus or a bonus based on the time, perhaps the difference between the time and the average time, or another bonus if it is a high score. My specific implementation for completing a checkpoint looks as follows at the moment:

[image]

```
if (checkpointComplete) {
    ((Activity) this.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //
        }
    });
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    ((ParallaxActivity) getContext()).stopWatch.stop();
    paint.setTextSize(60);
    String s2 = "TIME TO REACH POINT \"" + Background.checkpoint + "\"\n";
    if (runOnce) {
        for (int q = 0; q < s2.length(); q++) {
            final String s2f = s2;
            final int r = q;
            ((Activity) this.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    checkpointtextview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    checkpointtextview.append(Character.toString(s2f.charAt(r)));
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
    String str = String.format("%03d", ((ParallaxActivity) this.getContext()).countUp);
    String s3 = "YOUR TIME                :   " + str;
    if (runOnce) {
        for (int q = 0; q < s3.length(); q++) {
            final String s3f = s3;
            final int r = q;
            ((Activity) this.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    checkpointtextview2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ADD8E6"));
                    checkpointtextview2.append(Character.toString(s3f.charAt(r)));

                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
        }
    }
    runOnce = false;
    // canvas.drawText("CHECKPOINT COMPLETE", (float) (screenWidth * 0.35), (float) (screenHeight * 0.45), paint);
    ((Activity) this.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((ParallaxActivity) getContext()).startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    ((ParallaxActivity) getContext()).stopWatch.setBase(((ParallaxActivity) getContext()).startTime);
                    ((ParallaxActivity) getContext()).stopWatch.start();
                    checkpointtextview.setText("");
                    checkpointtextview2.setText("");
                    checkpointtextview3.setText("");
                    checkpointtextview4.setText("");
                    checkpointtextview5.setText("");
                    checkpointtextview6.setText("");
                    String str = "Player 1  " + String.format("%06d", score);
                    tvId.setText(str);
                    scoring = false;
                    buggyXDistance = 0;
                    distanceDelta = 0;
                    retardation = 0;
                    checkpointComplete = false;
                    runOnce = true;

                }
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to calculate bonus for completing a checkpoint but how is it calculated? If we look at the original it looks like below.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to deduce the formula for calculating the bonus? My bonus screen looks the same. So if your time is x and the average time is y and the record is z, what is the formula?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about game development but a question about how a specific game implements its score system.

Comment: @Charanor What do you mean? The question is absolutely about game development. Read what you wrote yourself: "Implementing a score system"

Comment: Not all games have the same score system. One game might have `best - time/average` and another might have `log(best) * average - min` or literally any other formula. What this question does is ask how the game in your picture implements their score system. If I have misunderstood and you're asking about a general score system it would help if you rephrased your question and address 1) Exactly what you need help with 2) What you have tried 3) Why it didn't work (what happened and was the expected result?).

Comment: @Charanor I am being specific about a specific scoring system. Do you have a problem with that?

Comment: We don't know how Moon Patrol implemented their scoring system. This is a question that you should ask the developers of that game.

Comment: While we can help you design a scoring system, we'll need more information to be able to separate proposals that would be suitable for your game's needs from those that would be unsuitable. Try taking a look at the [tag guidance for game design questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info), and edit your post to clearly explain your mechanics and the player experience goals or outcomes you want from the scoring feature. The more specific you can be about its inputs and desired (or undesired) outputs, the better our chances of finding a formula that meets those specs.

Comment: I have tried to improve the question now. My desire is to be as similar to Moon Patrol as possible.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 It is not so much the implementation as the formula. How is the bonus calculated mathematically i.e. do you get a fixed bonus for passing the checkpoint or does it depend on the time and if so, how?

Comment: That's still a detail of a specific game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is available at [this link](https://atariage.com/manual_html_page.php?SoftwareLabelID=888):

```
COURSE ONE                                POINTS
Completing each section of five markers     1000
Each second under 55 seconds it takes        100
to complete section 1 or 2
Each second under 60 seconds it takes        100
to complete section 3 or 4
Each second under 65 seconds it takes        100
to complete section 5
Completing the entire first course          5000
```